# Force variable to a type after conditional check

Tags: typescript

I wrote a function called isObject, which check if an value.constructor is that of an Object.

```
const value:any = {};

if ( isObject(value) ) {
  // value type is still "any"
  // I want value type here to be known as {}
  // How do I do that?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Typescript's [Type Predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates), but it requires you to modify the isObject function:

```
isObject(val: any): val is Object {
  // return true if object, false if not.
}
```